# How to change legend icon in plotly for bar and scatter graph?

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

I have following code -

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=stepCountDf['ActivityMinute'], y=stepCountDf['Steps'], marker_color='green',name = 'StepCount'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=heartRateDf['Time'], y=heartRateDf['Value'], mode='lines', marker_color='red', name='Heart Rate'))
fig.show()
```

It is creating square icon for Bar subplot legend and line icon for scatter plot legend.
[image]

I want to create same icon for both the plot. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the legend symbols for different traces using the **legendgroup** parameter.

Try like this

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=stepCountDf['ActivityMinute'], y=stepCountDf['Steps'], marker_color='green', name='StepCount', legendgroup='group1'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=heartRateDf['Time'], y=heartRateDf['Value'], mode='lines', marker_color='red', name='Heart Rate', legendgroup='group1'))

# Customize the legend entries with the desired legend symbols
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(itemsizing='constant'))

fig.show()
```

Comment: I tried that, it is not working.